# Template metaprogramming mixed with classic name overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I wanted to make a simple function-applier-to-many-variables-at-once template, which works just fine, but I just don't feel contented enough. Here is working code:

```
#include <iostream>

// generated for last (or the only) variable sent to apply_to_many template overload
template<class Fun, class Type>
void apply_to_many(Fun fun, Type& current)
{
    current = fun(current);
}

// variadic template + variadic arguments, fun is applied to 
// current variable, and template is generated for the rest
template<class Fun, class Type, class ...Types>
void apply_to_many(Fun fun, Type& current, Types&... other_variables)
{
    current = fun(current);
    if(sizeof...(other_variables) > 0)
        apply_to_many(fun, other_variables...);
}

// simple function returning square of value
int square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

int main()
{
    // some ints
    int a{3}, b{4}, c{5}, d{6}, e{7};

    std::cout << a << '\t'
              << b << '\t'
              << c << '\t'
              << d << '\t'
              << e << std::endl;

    apply_to_many(square, a, b, c, d, e);

    std::cout << a << '\t'
              << b << '\t'
              << c << '\t'
              << d << '\t'
              << e << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3       4       5       6       7
9       16      25      36      49
```

Though `a b c d e` can be different types, like `int`, `double`, `complex<float>`, the function that is applied here is only for `int`s, so `int`s are squared like `int`s, `float`s are squared like `int`s, `complex<float>`es are squared like `int`s... Oh well, `complex<float>` just fails to convert. The point is - it would be nice to use classic overload that is provided for these types, like `std::sqrt`, or `std::pow`. But obviously we can't pass overloaded name to template without explicitly choosing one overload.

```
apply_to_many(std::sqrt, a, b, c, d, e); //error
```

As far as I know, we can't send template function as argument (which would be amazing, but probably tricky). I'll accept anything, even macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use generic lambda (C++14):

```
apply_to_many([](auto v) { return std::sqrt(v); }, a, b, c, d, e);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/782c6af65c9b40b9)

In c++11, you have to create your functor the old way:

```
struct Sqrt
{
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T value) const
    -> decltype(std::sqrt(value))
    {
        return std::sqrt(value);
    }
};
```

and later

```
apply_to_many(Sqrt{}, a, b, c, d, e);
```